# Hardest python generator interview question - python generator object of ranges of numbers

Tags: python, function, generator

got this one in a python course, still can't figure it out:

**Input** - a string of start and end points a of a desired range.

**Output** - a generator of numbers containing all the numbers in all of the ranges.

**The problem**: making a function, using only two generators expressions (no for loops).

**Example**:

Input:

```
list(parse_ranges("1-2,4-4,8-10"))
```

Desired output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```

what I've come to so far:

```
def parse_ranges(ranges_string):
    first_generator = ([int(i[0]),int(i[-1])] for i in ranges_string.split(','))
    second_generator = (range(j[0],j[1]) for j in first_generator)
    return second_generator
```

my output:

```
[range(1, 2), range(4, 4), range(8, 0)]
```

Comment: It has to be 2 generators, i.e. 1 wouldnt do? Bt wyou are using a for loop in your generator =]

Comment: why not iterate for each range in the second?

Comment: or `chain.from_iterable(range(j[0],j[1]) for j in first_generator)`

Comment: @DaniMesejo I would assume importing `itertools` (or `functools`) would be forbidden in a challenge like this.

Comment: @AKX. Why? Is an interview from a job right?

Comment: Also  `i for j in first_generator for i in range(j[0],j[1])` works

Comment: Can you clarify what you are struggling with? Why don't you apply ``range`` in the first loop?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! 
@MisterMiyagi, how would you solve it with `range()` at the first loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that does it, but I wouldn't recommend to write such unreadable code...

```
def parse_ranges(string):
    ranges = (tuple(map(int, (s.split('-')))) for s in string.split(','))
    return (x for r in ranges for x in range(r[0], r[1]+1) )


list(parse_ranges("1-2,4-4,8-10"))
# [1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I think this is what they meant...
didn't know about the `map()` function, so I learn a few new things from your code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
s = "1-2,4-4,8-10"


def parse_ranges(s):
    ranges = ((int(start), int(stop) + 1) for start, stop in (chunk.split('-') for chunk in s.split(',')))
    yield from (i for start, end in ranges for i in range(start, end))


print(list(parse_ranges(s)))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```